# How to prevent remote desktop window from resizing itself when dragging it on the windows desktop?

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, remote-desktop, 4k-resolution

Since Windows 10 and now Windows 11 have come out, a "feature" that drives me crazy, is that, whenever you have a remote desktop screen/window open, it 1) opens, partially minimized at the top left of the desktop [which means, every time I have to resize it to the full size (not full screen) set in the RDP file] and 2) when dragging the window with the mouse via the title bar, it does the same thing [shrinks a little bit, forcing me to manually resize it again].
For example, you have a 4K monitor and you have RDP connection files, for a remote machine, set to 1920x1080, when you first start the RDP session, instead of a 1920x1080 window, you get a partially minimized window that's a bit smaller (even though you have plenty of desktop space) with horizontal and vertical scrollbars that ALWAYS loads at the top left of the screen.
You can resize it, manually to the right dimensions, but if you attempt to move it (say over to the right of your screen), it shrinks again (and happens even if your RDP window is well within the bounds of the desktop)!
Is there any hack, registry setting, or hidden setting that can prevent this from happening?

Comment: That should not happen. It only happens if you press maximize rather than drag the borders out to resize. Are you running any software that does window management, such as aligning it to a grid, etc? Also, try positioning the window at the place and size you prefer, then hold CTRL and while holding, click the x to close the window. This should save its position and relaunches it to that location automatically.

Comment: Reproduce by creating an RDP session file, set the fixed resolution to something less than the screen resolution, connect to your session. The RDP session window always starts on the top left of the screen w/scroll bars. You can click the maximize button to resize, however, as soon as you try to move the RDP session window with a mouse drag (via the title bar), say to the right, it re-shrinks.

Comment: If you then try to maximize the RDP session window (from anywhere on the screen), it snaps back to the top left.

Comment: If, say, you have a 1920x1080 RDP session window in the center of the screen (screen is say 4K), and it's the fully expanded (actual size of 1920x1080), all you have to do to reproduce the effect is to click on the title bar and drag in any direction. When you release the mouse button, the session window shrinks & has scroll bars (this ONLY happens with RDP - not any other window or program).

Comment: Did you try to delete your Default.rdp in your documents(or edit it so its default state is up for your needs)?

Comment: Tried this, but there's no setting for "keep remote desktop window from shrinking when moving".  This affects all Windows 10 machines, all configured differently, so it's an inherent property. This has been going on since Win10 was released. Win 8.1 and earlier did have this effect.